# OsmAnd: Show only POIs from my OBF file

Tags: osmand

I have created an [OBF file](http://datahub.io/dataset/wikivoyage-listings-as-obf) (OsmAnd POIs), and would like to display its POIs.

**PROBLEM**: When I enable POI display, tons of orange circles make the map unreadable. 99.99% of these POIs are not from my OBF file, they are from the base OSM map.

[image: OsmAnd POI orange circles]

**QUESTION**: How can I show only the POIs from my OBF file?

I can modify the OBF file if needed, for instance adding attributes or changing POI type if needed.

In the layers settings I see a "Create POI filter" dialog with a "User defined" item, might it be part of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Quickly skimming OsmAnd~ on my phone I believe it is not possible in current version (1.9.x) to filter displayed POI by their source. You'd have to tag them so that you can apply a custom filter or you have to disable other sources in settings.